Prove that in 8 different numbers less equal than $15$ there are at least $3$ pairs of numbers that have the same difference.
Im trying to prove this using pigeon hole principle, if there are $8$ numbers then there are $28$ possible difference values (the diff between the first and each of the remaining $7$ numbers and then second with with the remaining $6$ and so on..- an arithemetic series), and then the possible values for them can be from $1$ to $14$ so with this info I reach the conclusion that there at least $[\frac{28}{14}]=2$ pairs that have the same difference but it should be $3$, what did i miss?

What do you mean by "numbers"?  Positive integers?  Non-zero integers?  Something else?

Note:  only the pair $(14,1)$ has a difference of $13$.

Positive integers, can you explain further how the fact that theres only one pair helps?

Well, you said the only bad scenario was to have two of each possible difference, right?  Note: I said the wrong numbers though. Should have said that only the pair $(15,1)$ has a difference of $14$.  The numbers themselves are unimportant (though one should get them straight).  The point is that there is one difference that only occurs once.

Now i get it, thank you^^

The difference between pairs are $\{1,2,3,...,14\}$
There is only a pair makes $14$ that is $(1,15)$
There are only two pairs make $13$ that is $(1,14), (2,15)$
Total number of pairs is $\binom{8}{2}=28$
and $2\times 11 +3 = 25$
at least $3$ pairs have the same difference.

I don't understand the closing argument $2\times 11 +3 = 25$, I suppose you subtracted the number of pairs (3) discussed above from the total number of pairs, that is $28-3=25$, but I don't understand why. feel free to answer on my question

@powerline Two of the holes (holes #13 and #14) have limited capacity, so at least $28-3 = 25$ pigeons have to fit in the remaining $12$ holes (#1 to #12). I would find the answer clearer if it meant $2\times 12 +3 = 27$ instead.

@peterwhy yes, that's it I understand now. thanks
